# How to rotate an elliptical orbit using Animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

I have some objects in the same vertice locations of a circle, but this circle should be an ellipse and rotate its orbit, I tried to use a lattice and it worked for the circle, but then the objects didn't follow the new vertices locations.

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you applied the lattice modifier?

Comment: If you are using mesh input node then enable "Use Modifiers"

Comment: Thank you! It was so simple but I just didn't notice this option.